# Keeping UIButton Stationary on Screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uibutton, zooming

I have a UIButton on top of a UIWebView. The UIButton is supposed to look like it's native to the webpage. However, when I zoom in on the UIWebView, the button comes with it, obviously looking out of place. Is there a way to keep the button's position relative to the UIWebView rather than its position on screen?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've understood your problem, but here goes:

You've likely a view hierarchy like this:

- View

  - UIWebView

    - UIButton

That is, your button was added as subview to the UIWebView. Since the UIWebView is also a UIScrollView you get the behavior you've observed. To fix it, make the button a sibling, not a child:

- View

  - UIWebView
  - UIButton

It will still be drawn in front of your UIWebView if it was added after the UIWebView.

Comment: I changed `[webView addSubview:refreshButton]` to `[self.view addSubview:refreshButton]`. No luck. What I want is to be able to zoom in and have the button disappear and stay in the same place relative to the UIWebView. Let me know if I need to make the question more clear, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *"disappear and stay in the same place"* doesn't make much sense to me, I'm afraid. Also, I don't understand what you mean with *"relative to the UIWebView"*.

Comment: Sorry. Basically, the UIWebView takes up the entire screen. I want a button on top of the webview in the top right corner. However, when I zoom in on the bottom left corner, let's say, I want the button to be out of the scope of the webview at that point, along with the rest of the top right corner and any other areas that cannot be seen because of the zoom. Right now, the button stays in the top right corner of the screen when I zoom in. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: Maybe, it now sounds a little like you want the opposite of what I assumed. I was also wrong about the UIWebView being a scroll view, it just has one as subview. So try: `[[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:refreshButton];`